# Why does NextJS allow the development server to run, but not the production server?

Tags: reactjs, windows, networking, next.js, netstat

On my dev machine I have some Ivanti application service running at 'TCP 0.0.0.0:3000' according to netstat. Running `npm run dev` works and netstat then shows two entries for 'TCP 0.0.0.0:3000'. When started I get:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
```

but when I run `npm start` after quitting my dev server I get the error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:3000  
...  
code: 'EADDRINUSE',  
errno: -4091,  
syscall: 'listen',  
address: '0.0.0.0',  
port: 3000
```

How is it that I'm able to run the dev server but not the prod server given they seem to be requesting the same resource ... which seems to already be used.

Comment: why not just start prod server on custom port? like `PORT=3001 npm run start`

Comment: @VladVladov I do that, but that doesn't explain why one works and one doesn't